# How to implement input click select range

Tags: javascript, html, css

see my gif, I hope custom `input type=datatime-local` time format to "yy-mm-dd", so I hope impl datetime input similar click event, when click input value, select specific range, how to impl

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a the same question:

[Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)